# How do I close a question as a duplicate of more than one question?

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

Sometimes I'll find two questions that could be duplicates of the OP's question, and I don't know how to vote the question as a duplicate of both the other ones.

I've tried to separate them by comma or plus sign in the closing duplicate tab but that did not work.

Comment: Gold tag-badge holders can do that and add more duplicate links to the banner. You should leave another hand crafted comment.

Comment: Are they similar (in that case do a A -> C, B -> C) or different (in that case use Too Broad)?

Comment: If the question isn't a duplicate of either by itself, then it isn't a duplicate regardless. You don't close a question as saying "If you combine the information found in these two separate and distinct questions, you'll have your answer". That doesn't make any sense

Comment: Parallel question from MSE - [Closing a question with multiple duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332023/closing-a-question-with-multiple-duplicates)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How to close a question as duplicate with closing for more than one question?

Only **gold tag-badge** holders and **moderators** can close a question as a duplicate of more than one question.

EX. check below screenshot

[image]

Check this related post on MSE [Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links)

Comment: Thanks, now i know, i don't have gold tag-badges yet so i am unable to do that, so i will work hard for it :-), , only able to accept in 10 minutes...

Comment: @U9-Forward  `i will work hard for it ` best of luck for that

Comment: Wow, okay, got a silver badge at least:-)

Comment: Wow, totally new interface for having gold-tag-badges

Comment: This isn't quite accurate. If different users who are close-voting select different duplicate-target questions, then all selected duplicate-target questions will be included in the list of duplicates, once the question is closed. So, while gold-badge holders and moderators are the ones that can put more than one question in the duplicate list by themselves, a regular close-voter can choose to select a duplicate-target question which is not already selected by the existing close-votes. This will result in the target question being in the dup list, once the question is closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the answer by Nilesh, it should be noted that most of the time we should only pick one duplicate. Preferably a "canonical" one if such a question exists.

It may however be appropriate to have 2 or more in the case where one link definitely answers the specific question, and the other link is a canonical dupe explaining the general principles that the question was about.

For example, if someone asks a C or C++ question "Why doesn't `i = i + ++i;` work as I expected?", we can use [Why are these constructs using pre- and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior) as one dupe to answer the specific question and [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) as further study material on the topic.

That is, don't use 2 or more close dupes unless the links are canonical high quality ones, like the ones in my example. It adds nothing for the OP if we just stack up multiple mediocre dupes.

Comment: Thanks, now i know, i don't have gold tag-badges yet so i am unable to do that, so i will work hard for it :-), 

Comment: Here's a direct counterexample of pick one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602111/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-the-local-timezone In this case neither question alone could have been the dupe target.

Answer (score 4):

Since now I got gold-tag-badges, this is what I get for the vision:

[image]

And hitting the edit button does it.

After editing links:

[image]