# Are multiple close reasons provided if a question was single-handedly closed?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, dupehammer

I came across the following post and revisions:

- [command won't add roles to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77107942/command-wont-add-roles-to-the-user?noredirect=1#comment135932386_77107942)
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77107942/revisions

It was closed by two users, one with the ability to single-handedly close the question. If the question is closed and both link to a different duplicate post, which one is displayed?

Just leaving a note here as well that the now linked question has nothing to do with the original question, as it deals with a different language. OP uses Python, and it was closed with a link to a JavaScript post.

Comment: I may be wrong, but gold badge holders may be able to edit in additional duplicate targets.  That said, moderators definitely can, so regardless of getting the question in question more attention here on meta, you should also flag for moderator attention I believe, explaining the issue in detail.

Comment: @Daedalus I already went ahead and voted to reopen the question. I can, in addition, flag it for maybe a faster reaction though – thanks!

Comment: If the question does indeed have a better duplicate target, I'd include that target in the flag.  As to flags being faster, that's not entirely true; there are only so many moderators, and a sea of flags.

Comment: To be clear, are you specifically asking about multiple duplicate targets, or multiple different close reasons other than just duplicates?

Comment: Addressing @JohnMontgomery's point, it is possible for multiple close reasons (as opposed to multiple duplicate targets) to show, but [it only happens for community-specific reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351259/165261), and on Stack Overflow it can only happen if a moderator is the third close voter and picks a different reason than the other two, both of whom pick the same reason as each other.

Comment: @Dominik " I already went ahead and voted to reopen the question" - did you confirm that typo (not calling a function) is indeed typo before voting to reopen (as generally we should not be re-opening questions that should be closed)?  Consider fixing the post before re-opening (while somewhat controversial, such edit would be ok if verified to still be a problem). I'd personally recommend to ping gold badge user to ask if they mis-pasted the link...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's particularly unfortunate if it stays up as a misleading duplicate, though...since I'm already here, if the OP confirms it's a typo, someone ping me and I'll re-close for that reason.

Comment: @RyanM I personally suspect the duplicate was not wrong - I don't know about this particular case, but many APIs are built to be essentially identical between languages (to the point of copy-paste working across multiple languages). There is very good chance that just pasting the same lines from JS sample to python code would work... While technically against SO guidelines it maybe rude to assume OP is unable to even copy-paste samples....  Anyway, thanks for the offer - right now the linked post stands open with code that clearly can't work - downvote magnet...

Comment: So this is specifically about multiple duplicate links and not about close reasons in general? If so, the title is kind of misleading currently :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov There wasn't much for me to correct after all the other edits without adding details I don't have knowledge of. While JS and Python may have similar functions, the linked post was not helpful at all, since code-structure and the “how-to-do-that” were very different in that case. Thank you for the tip though, did that right after I noticed! :)

Comment: @Gimby How would you phrase it? “Close reasons” refers to the message that is displayed above the question, which also includes the link(s).

Comment: @Dominik "Close reasons" implies all close reasons (opinion-based, unclear, etc.), not just duplicates. "Duplicate targets" is probably the phrase you're looking for, unless you're indeed asking about all close reasons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If people use different duplicate-targets when voting to close a question, then all targets will be shown regardless of whether a dupe-hammer was involved.
[Gold-badge holders can add/remove/change the duplicate targets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375711/how-do-i-close-a-question-as-a-duplicate-of-more-than-one-question). It is displayed in the timeline when they do so.

In the example you gave, we can tell (from the timeline) that the duplicate list hasn't been modified after it was closed. So the first close-voter either voted to close as a duplicate of the same target, or voted to close the question for a different reason.

Looking beyond the duplicate-closure spectrum, it's a bit more complicated. Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog has described the logic [in great detail on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339401/398364).